# listenTo model attribute in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to listen to a specific attribute (`transitions`, a number count) of a model.   In a view, I have `this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', _.bind(this.transition, this));`
 which listens to the entire model change event.   Howeverm the following isn't working:

```
  this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:transitions', _.bind(this.transition, this));
```

What syntax structure should I use, or method call?  If a different BB method call is required, what is the difference?

Model:

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {
  var RepresentationModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(options){
      this.representationType = options.representationType;
      this.previousRepresentationType = undefined;
      this.transitions = 0;
    },
    transition: function(newRep){
      this.set({
        previousRepresentationType: this.representationType,
        representationType: newRep,
        transitions: this.transitions+1
      });
    }
  });
  return RepresentationModel;
});
```

Listening View:

```
...
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', _.bind(this.transition, this));
...
```

Calling View: (differen from listening View)

```
var measureRepColl = StageCollection.get(hTrackCID).get('measures').models[0].get('measureRepresentations').get(measureRepCID).transition(newRepType);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have should work. Most likely the model isn't firing the `change:transitions` change event for other reasons. Investigate (or post snippets) of the code that you are expecting to set the `transitions` attribute on the model.

---

Side note you can specify a context and thus don't need `_.bind`:  `this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:transitions', this.transition, this);`